# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python 3.11.4\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python 3.11.4\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 71, in driver_location
    browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\Exoplanet-web Scrapping\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Web Drivers/chromedriver")
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python 3.11.4\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Python 3.11.4\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python 3.11.4\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 40, in get_path
    msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'
```

This is the Error

This is occuring while runing this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

START_URL = "https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/discovery/exoplanet-catalog/"
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Web Drivers/chromedriver")
browser.get(START_URL)
time.sleep(10)

def scrape():
    headers = ["name","light_years_from_earth","planet_mass","stellar_magnitude","discovery_data"]
    planet_data = []
    for i in range(0,428):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,"html_parser")
        for ul_tag in soup.find_all("ul",attrs = {"class","exoplanet"}):
            li_tags = ul_tag.find_all("li")
            temp_list = []
            for index, li_tag in enumerate(li_tags):
                if index == 0:
                    temp_list.append(soup.find_all("a"[0].contents[0]))
                else:
                    try:
                        temp_list.append(li_tag.contents[0])
                    except:
                        temp_list.append("")
            planet_data.append(temp_list)
        browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/section[2]/div/section[2]/div/div/article/div/div[2]").click()
    with open("scrapper_2.csv","w") as f:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
        csvwriter.writerow(headers)
        csvwriter.writerows(planet_data)
        
scrape()
```

I am working on a project named Web Scrapping and when I am runining this comand through the

cmd as adminstrator

I am trying to generate a csv file of the data given on this website:

https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/discovery/exoplanet-catalog/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Web Drivers/chromedriver")
```

Try:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: Or `browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/"Web Drivers"/chromedriver')` - Whitespace between words in a path can be tricky.

Comment: browser = webdriver.Chrome() for this i need to add the orginal path of the webdriver to environment